# Extra div added on chrome while copy paste into contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, contenteditable

I have contenteditable div i want only raw text instead of HTML content while copy paste from any website. I got some solution and tried out the following

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') || prompt('Paste something..');
    window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
});
```

it works fine but the problem is it adds extra div in chrome browser.

Any idea or better solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same kind of problem, And it also adds & etc sometimes. I used the below regular expression to delete all the html tags. 
When you call the blur event, inside the function use the below code to remove tags. It also works even if you copy and paste the content in the editable div.

```
x = x.replace(/(<[^\\>]*>|<br\/>|&amp;|amp;|&lt|&gt;)/g, '');
x = x.trim();
```

Hope this ia what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

We can use .text() function of jquery to remove all the HTML tags.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();

    $(this).text(text);
});
```